# Does ClosedXML support setting a worksheet's zoom level?

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I am using [closedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) to generate an Excel file from C# and I am trying to see if there is anyway to set the zoom level of a worksheet. I can't find this in any of the documentation or from googling?

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean page scaling [http://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pages%20Tab&referringTitle=Documentation](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pages%20Tab&referringTitle=Documentation)?

Comment: @johny - i am not talking about printing . . i am talking about the regular zoom at the bottom right of a worksheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update for version 0.87+:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/52755386/2610249

---

No, ClosedXML does not support setting the zoom. The [option that johny links to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877710/does-closedxml-support-setting-a-worksheets-zoom-level#comment29590513_19877710) is only for scaling of the pages when printing.

There is a [feature request](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/discussions/249997) on the ClosedXML page, but no answer from the developer.

Comment: The Codeplex site is obsolete. ClosedXML has moved to Github.

Answer (score 7):

It's now possible, starting with ClosedXML version 0.87.0, via the `IXLSheetView.ZoomScale` property.

```
using Excel = ClosedXML.Excel;

var wb = new Excel.XLWorkbook();
Excel.IXLWorksheet ws = wb.AddWorksheet("zoom");
Excel.IXLSheetView view = ws.SheetView;

/* Value can be set between 10 and 400 */
view.ZoomScale = 85;
```

You can check the [IXLSheetView source code](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/blob/master/ClosedXML/Excel/IXLSheetView.cs) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

As previously answered, you can't, but I've found a way around it which works well:

Create a template Excel file in advance, with all sheets' zoom levels set to how you want them.

When you create your workbook, instead of:

```
    public XLWorkbook CreateWorkbook()
    {
        XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook();
        IXLWorksheet worksheet = workbook.AddWorksheet("First sheet");

        // ...

        return workbook;
    }
```

do this:

```
    public XLWorkbook CreateWorkbookWithZoom()
    {
        XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(@"C:\your template file.xlsx");
        IXLWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheet(1);
        worksheet.Name = "First sheet";

        // ...

        return workbook;
    }
```

where `C:\your template file.xlsx` is the path of your template file.

I think you can also handle having a variable number of sheets, by copying existing (blank) worksheets instead of creating new ones. You can get creative with having different blank template worksheets to choose from, if you need to set the zoom level dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

A pull request for this has been logged at https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/pull/180